# angular-three does not work with angular16+

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js

i want to include angular-three in my angular project. however, i get the error that the module is not angular16+ compatible. Are there any other options besides going to a lower angular version? `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps` dont work. i would like to keep the angular16+ features. with a lower angular version it works, but this is not an option for me, because i depend on other dependencies [image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)